# Rspec with cmd fixing encodings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cmd

I am following the Mhartl Ruby on Rails tutorial and beginning to use Rspec. I was wondering if there is a way to fix what I assume are end of line characters that are not properly encoded when outputting to cmd such as: ←[0m

```
C:\PROGRAMMING\RailsSites\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[31mF←[0m

Failures:

  1) Static Pages About page should have the content 'About Us'
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mvisit '/static_pages/about'←[0m
     ←[31mActionController::RoutingError:←[0m
       ←[31mNo route matches [GET] "/static_pages/about"←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m

Finished in 3.66 seconds
←[31m3 examples, 1 failure←[0m

Failed examples:

←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19←[0m ←[36m# Static Pages About page should have the content 'About Us'←[0m
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the ANSI color codes to actually do something in CMD before I just disable them?

Comment: The built in windows shell (CMD) is notoriously horrible compared to the unix/linux shells.  I have no idea if there's a way to get the ANSI color codes to display or not.

Comment: Cygwin vs RailsInstaller and native windows development is horrible.

Comment: I just noticed this in the RSpec source: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L413-421 -- could be helpful to get this to work on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the [ANSI codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) to colorize the text.

Pass the `--no-color` option when you run the rspec command to disable these codes.  You can also add `--no-color` to your `.rspec` file to make it a default option for your project.

Comment: For now I will accept this. If there is a way to pimpmycmd I am all ears.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

[ANSI Command Line Colors under Windows](http://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows/)

It worked on my aged XP machine, and it worked on W7 for the blog author, it probably works for you as well. It zeroed my cmd history BTW, but it looks like its back after the first test.